# Identifier not found, even with argument-dependent lookup

Tags: c++

I have this function:

```
short cmd_Draw2DPoly(short ThreeDmode, sds_point startpoint[]){...}
```

and I call it like this in another class

```
cmd_Draw2DPoly(0, startpoint);
```

and this error shows up

```
error C3861: 'cmd_Draw2DPoly': identifier not found, even with argument-dependent lookup
```

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Comment: The function is not in scope where you're attempting to call it. It's possible you forgot to declare it, but I'm just guessing because you _did not provide a testcase_.

Comment: The key question is **where** do you have the function `cmd_Draw2DPoly`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call your member function from another class, you need to pass the object on which to call it.

```
someObject.cmd_Draw2DPoly(0, startpoint);
```

Comment: What leads you to think that cmd_Draw2DPoly is a member function?

Comment: @Jan, the question used "method" when I wrote my answer, and while method isn't part of the C++ vocabulary, the most common use is for member function of some sort (the nearest of its original SmallTalk signification would be to restrict it to virtual member, but that would probably assuming too much).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call methods of a class without specifying the instance of that class. So if `cmd_Draw2DPoly` isn't a standalone function and is not a member of "another class" you can't call it like that.

Comment: What leads you to think that cmd_Draw2DPoly is a method?

Comment: @Jan Hudec, OP said "in another class" which make me think that there's one class and another class. That's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your profile makes me think you are a Java developer and you may be  not familiar with the concept of `namespace` in C++ that may open and close in the middle of a file (unlike Java package that is extended to entire file). So check for the presence of such a block that may enclose the definition of cmd_Draw2DPoly.